# Erro com LEFT JOIN em LINQ

Tags: linq

A minha query está retornando como erro

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Quando tento fazer uma categoria que não possui produto exibir "(Inexistente)":

```
        var lst = from c in BDProduto.categorias
                  join p in BDProduto.produtos on c.IdCategoria equals p.IdCategoria into g
                  from gr in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new
                  {
                      IDCategoria = gr.IdCategoria,
                      Categoria = gr.Categoria,
                      IDProduto = gr.IdProduto,
                      Produto = gr == null ? "(Inexistente)" : gr.Produto
                  };

        foreach (var item in lst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IDCategoria: {0}, Categoria: {1}, IDProduto: {2}, Produto: {3}",
                              item.IDCategoria, item.Categoria, item.IDProduto, item.Produto);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você não pode acessar uma propriedade de um objeto Nulo, no caso o `gr`, mas acredito que `IdCategoria`, `Categoria` e `IdProduto` sejam propriedades de `c`, então faça assim:

```
var lst = 
    from categoria in BDProduto.categorias
    join produto in BDProduto.produtos on categoria.IdCategoria equals produto.IdCategoria into ljProduto
    from lProduto in ljProduto.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        IDCategoria = categoria.IdCategoria,
        Categoria = categoria.Categoria,
        IDProduto = categoria.IdProduto,
        Produto = lProduto == null ? "(Inexistente)" : lProduto.Produto
    };

foreach (var item in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IDCategoria: {0}, Categoria: {1}, IDProduto: {2}, Produto: {3}",
                      item.IDCategoria, item.Categoria, item.IDProduto, item.Produto);
}
```

Comment: Toby, o seu código funcionou, mas IdProduto não aparece resultado, retorna sempre 0 (zero). Ele faz parte de Produto, só a propriedade IdCategoria que faz parte de Produto e Categoria.

Comment: @KellySoares, Neste caso você precisa fazer com IDProduto o mesmo que fez com Produto, verifique se o objeto é nulo antes de tentar acessar produto.IdProduto